# In iwork Pages, how to start a new line after the last row of a table?

Tags: pages, iwork

I evidently don't know the right thing to look for.  The last thing in my document is a table.  There is no paragraph after it.  I can go on adding rows to the table with the context menu, or add paragraphs to a cell of the table by pressing 'return'.

But I can't seem to add a paragraph after the table without doing something hacky like cutting the table, inserting to newlines, and then pasting the table back.

There should be a way to do this, but I can't find the key words to find it either in google or the pages handbook.

(Haven't used any ms or open document document things for a long time, so when I had a need for a document full of tables I bought Pages.  I like it pretty well).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try clicking off the table (so you aren't in a cell) then click the table to select it, and then pressing the right-arrow when the table is lit as selected?

Comment: This works.  Where could I find this?

Comment: Do you mean where can you find it documented? Not sure. I just think of the table object like an embedded image.